# Software for manage small business goods?

Tags: information-management, inventory

I work for a small multimedia and video company, and I'm looking for a software that let me manage all the goods of the company, like: from cameras, lens, lights, laptops, audio devices... to tables, fridges, coolers, chairs... and even cranes. Like an inventory of those goods, with serial numbers I can track, technical specifications, and even borrowings and use in locations.

All the inventory softwares I reviewed are for manage clients, buyers, sellers, prices, invoices, storage and that kind of things that are more like for stores or depot business. That's not what I'm looking... I just want a software that let me manage the goods of the video company I'm working, for know all the goods the company have, their state, technical info, and so.

Preffered I'm looking for a free software, but paid one works either. Ah, I don't want cloud, internet or online software, the database and the software need to be all offline, in my hard drive, without internet at all.

Comment: What's wrong with a spreadsheet?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek a spreadsheet is what we have now... But it's too manual and dificult to maintaing with tech specification and other stuff. We're looking for something more automatic that also generate serial numbers for those goods, with the capability of generate informs and make simple maths, features that this softwares usually have.

Comment: @FiroKun You should post these clarifications and additional specifics as edits to your Question rather than as comments.